# Align text center vertically in tab Host

Tags: android

I want to set the text at center vertcally in tab host. I tried gravity to center but still not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Where did you set the gravity?

Comment: I tried with all Tabhost, Linearlayout, TabWidget, Framelayout simultaneously.

Comment: @Android I don't see `android:gravity` anywhere in your layout. Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 4):

Do that programatically:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        // setup your tabs

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title).setLayoutParams(rllp);
        }
```