# Change text alignment in TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, alignment

Original Quesetion:

Is there a way to change the text alignment for a tabhost indicator? I would like to have the text float right. How would this be done?

EDIT: This is what I have implemented to get it working.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

int current = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)  
{  
    TextView txt = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    txt.setLayoutParams(rllp);
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

Comment: Look here for solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477496/align-text-center-vertically-in-tab-host)

Comment: @BoskoMijin that link helped

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of `setIndicator()` on `TabHost.TabSpec` that takes a `View`, and supply your own indicator view, where the text is aligned as you see fit.